# Filter Date to week excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

### Filter Date to week excel

Hello everyone

I got the date like this `31/12/2016`

What i want is when I get the date I can know whitch week it locate.

Like `01/01/2016` is in the `1` week

Do you know how to do it with excel instead of use VB ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's formatted as a date in the format of "dd/mm/yyyy", just use Excel function **WEEKNUM**.

In your case: `=WEEKNUM(31/12/2016)`

If your are keeping the value of `31/12/2016` in **Cell A1**, and you want to get the WeekNumber in **Cell B1**, just write in Cell B1 = `=WEEKNUM(A1)`

Result in Excel 2010 (I got using this) :

[image]

Comment: @YiaoSun very strange, look at the scree-shot I've attached when I use this formula

Comment: maybe is the problem of language of excel, i use the version Franch but thank you very much